# Matplotlib + Qt: tight_layout() doesn't work on the first draw

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt4

Using `PyQt4` and `matplotlib` I have connected a button click to perform some calculation and render a graph. The `tight_layout()` only applies after clicking the button a second time.

When I'm done setting up the axes and putting data on the graph, I call

```
fig.tight_layout()
fig.canvas.draw()
```

I've tried to fake a second button press without success:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
fig.tight_layout()
fig.canvas.draw()
QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
fig.tight_layout()
fig.canvas.draw()
```

My thought was that the Qt surface wasn't recognized as dirty, but resizing the window redraws the chart with the same loose layout. The tight layout does apply when I clear the axes and repopulate the chart.

How can I make `tight_layout()` apply the first time the graph is drawn?

Comment: as a side note, don't mix embedding with `pyplot` (I can't tell from this code if you are or not, but that could be messing you up)

Comment: Yeah, seems like if `pyplot` is imported at all, drawing winds up on the wrong figure. The code causing this issue doesn't have any reference to `pyplot`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's no need to explicitly call `draw` or `processEvents`. Instead, I just needed a call to `canvas.updateGeometry()`.